# Method of pasting "smoothly-typed" text for demo videos?

Tags: video, webvideos, tutorial

I often see in demo videos, whenever text is required to be filled in (such as when filling out forms), that the text is entered smoothly, not actually typed by the person shooting the video.

Wondering if anyone knows of a good method(s) of achieving said effect, as it looks much more professional than manually typing text while recording. I'm assuming there is an app(s) that allows someone to paste in text so that it is entered like this, but I can't find anything online so far.

Answer (score 1):

Allmost any video editing software has a "typewriter"-effect or similar called. This one should do exactly what you want and you have the control of several parameters as smoothiness and speed.

Comment: Thanks. But this is just an effect in the video itself, correct? I was looking something that will actually fill in the form so I can submit it and go on to the next step! Or will I have to just do this with editing? PS - I use ScreenFlow, I will have to see what they have for that. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like nothing for ScreenFlow. I ended up recording a small section of screen using this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/ and then faking it in the video editor. Took longer than I wanted but I achieved the effect I was going for. Thanks @romeoyankee !